# executing stored requests in a table and getting the values into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I have a table T1 with a column 1 where I store some SQL requests in the pattern " select Var1 from T2". But the problem is that when I put "select A1 from T1" I get the request only in a form of a string. Is there any way to execute the requests stored in the column A1 and return the value into a variable ??

Thanks for Help in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create a SQL statement and then run that command

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test89
 (
  Id int,
  Var1 nvarchar(1)
  )

INSERT dbo.test89
VALUES(1, 'A'),
      (2, 'B')

CREATE TABLE dbo.test90
 (
  Id int,
  Col1 nvarchar(max)
  )

INSERT dbo.test90
VALUES(1, 'SELECT Var1 FROM dbo.test89')

DECLARE @dsql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @varTable TABLE(Var1 nvarchar(1))
SELECT @dsql = Col1
FROM dbo.test90
WHERE Id = 1
INSERT @varTable
EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
SELECT *
FROM @varTable
```